# How do I restrict a Concourse `github-release` resource to a major version

Tags: concourse

The github release resource allows us to set a version, but as far as I can tell, that just sets a floor on the version we'll accept: it will give us anything newer than that version.

We're looking for a way to accept versions based on semver positions.  In our case, we want to ensure we don't automatically accept a major revision bump.

For example, we want the latest 4.x.x, but we don't want 5.anything.

We can achieve a similar effect using the `git` resource's `tag_filter` Source Configuration.  We'd like a similar facility in `github-release` resource.

Answer (score 0):

The `github-release` resource doesn't currently support this type of filtering based on tag versions.

Could you please [submit an issue on the resource](https://github.com/concourse/github-release-resource/issues/new) for this?